# how do I fix this code - variable not defined in function

Tags: python, function

I'm having trouble understand how to fix the below code so the function will print a_string in reverse. I know rev is not defined...just couldn't figure out how to make it work. Any help would be great, thanks.

```
def reverse(a_string):

  for i in range(len(a_string)-1, -1, -1):
    rev =rev+ a_string[i]
    return rev
reverse("cat")
print(rev)
```

Comment: Set `rev` to an empty string before the for loop.

Comment: I done that but still error says undefined ---> rev=""  between def & for?

Comment: You have to define the variable before you use it.  See any tutorial on accumulating results -- in your case, likely covered in a tutorial on string processing.

Comment: Since your  print statement is outside of your function you'll have to define rev outside your funciton as well i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to define rev so python stores it as a string type: rev = ""
So your code could look like this:

```
def reverse(a_string):
    rev = ""
    for i in range(len(a_string)-1, -1, -1):
        rev += a_string[i]
    return rev
print(reverse("cat"))
```

For the last line [print(rev)], you cannot print the rev variable since it is stored within the function and is not a global variable. So to print the function output you use: print(reverse("cat")).

Comment: ty sir! this helps a lot...still a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder, why don't you do it this way:

```
return a_string[::-1]
```

Unless you wanna do it manually in purpose, of course.

Comment: its on purpose as an exercise problem to understand error defined outside functions